# Can accounts of deceased users be given a "deceased" indicator on their profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

It's going to happen, and probably has already - the user dies.

Subject to a reasonable process (email from relative, plus attempt to contact user, etc), set a flag on the user's profile to indicate they are no longer with the living.

Why? No really compelling reason; AFAIK Facebook has this feature, and it would prevent fruitless entreaties to contact them.

Comment: I don't think something like this is needed, especially as you say there's not really a compelling reason. For something like Facebook it makes more sense, as that's a social network; it's about the users. Here users are secondary to questions/answers.

Comment: No. This won't happen. Reason can be found in the top answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled and STACK EXCHANGE IS NO FACEBOOK!!

Comment: +1, it wil acknowledge the deceased contributors who helped others with their time and knowledge.

Comment: What percentage of experienced contributors would mark themselves as desceased if it prevented entreaties to contact them? I think this could become a very popular option, though not by those for whom it was intended.

Comment: @RobertLongson This option would probably make the account unable to contribute too.

Comment: We'd resurrect ourselves in order to answer questions. We'd be an entirely new form of help vampire.