# Is it acceptable to write in memoriam posts on per-site metas for people with strong ties to the site's subject matter?

Tags: discussion, questions, per-site-meta

I was browsing the *[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)* Meta site, when I saw this '[question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14055/in-memoriam-akira-toriyama).' It is a short [in memoriam](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_memoriam#Noun) for the creator of an incredibly popular anime (*[Dragon Ball Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z)*).

Should such types of questions be allowed on per-site metas, since they, well, aren't asking questions? More specifically, should questions like these posted on per-site metas be downvoted and/or closed?

This question is not asking just about this specific case - it is asking about the general case on per-site metas. Even if (as the comments say) similar questions have been asked on other meta sites, that doesn't mean that some sort of 'site-wide' answer would be bad.

Comment: I think this question does't need to be closed as only pertaining to a specific site, so I edited the title. that being said, if you had asked this on the SF&F meta, then this would be a duplicate of [Should meta posts regarding the deaths of figures that are important to SFF:SE be on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10444/159649) (where most there are in favour of these being on-topic _for their meta site_). they have [a whole tag for it](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-memoriam) with 112 questions right now.

Comment: another related example: [In memoriam: Bram Moolenaar](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1606/46994). there's also a related category of people who were _contributors_ to the site. Ex. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15738/468411, https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/65821, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19822/926489 (and related to that, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38742/997587)

Comment: @starball It should be closed as only pertaining to a single site, because the **only** place where this question can be answered is on the specific meta which is being asked about. It's *not possible* to answer this question for all meta sites here on MSE. The only thing that can be said here on MSE is A) if it's OK to post such questions here on MSE, and B) that you must ask this question on the on each specific meta site where you might want to post such questions.

Comment: @Makyen alright. not sure that I fully agree, but I'll take it as a learning and go with it.

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic I'd assume that people are downvoting because this isn't an issue which can be decided for all sites here on MSE and then imposed on each individual meta site. It's an issue which is **only** appropriate to be decided upon by the individual meta. People may see you asking this here as an attempt to get a Network-wide ruling to overturn the choice that's been made on SFF or some other site that might have decided that such posts aren't permitted. There's a considerable history of people trying to do that for things that are *very clearly* up to the individual site.

Comment: This is a question about topicality on individual meta sites. Topicality questions are **very strongly** in the hands of the individual site, with relatively few exceptions (e.g., clear spam, rude/abusive, CoC violations, etc.).

Comment: @Makyen but it's on topic here, as we can decide there's no blanket rule *against* such questions, i.e. it's not against any ToS or CoC etc. (Voted to reopen)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda The question from the OP was *very clearly* about the policy on a single meta site. Despite everyone seemingly wanting to generalize it in their minds, it remains primarily about the policy on a single site. Perhaps what we need is a different, general question that discusses the scope of what policies can be/should be imposed from MSE onto all sites. We don't need a billion questions asking about each individual meta-site policy, particularly not about topicality that's already been discussed and decided on that site meta.

Comment: @Makyen I have now edited the question so it's clear it asks generally instead of just for the one case.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Again, we shouldn't be having a bunch of questions which try to challenge topicality rulings on individual sites by attempting to establishing some over-policy. If you're wanting a *general* question that discusses what types of policies it's acceptable to make here on MSE, that might be a reasonable, different question, but we *really* shouldn't be supporting people coming here to challenge each individual topicality decision on other sites, particularly when it's already been discussed on the individual site, which is what this is doing.

Comment: @Makyen As far as your first sentence, that would be more of an answer to this question rather than a reason to close it. For your next sentence, do note that the directions in the close dialog state that the close reason should not be used on questions that can be applied to multiple sites even if they focus primarily on one site - the latest revision of this question at this time simply cites that post from SF&F Meta as an example.

Comment: @Makyen I don't think the request or point here is to challenge anything or create over-policy.

Answer (score 17):

I think it’s very much a matter of site *culture*. I realise that there's sometimes a desire for clear, common rules, but we are *communities* and especially on meta, sometimes it’s good for the communities to commemorate events of importance to us *in the community*.

On a site like [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), and specifically the *fields* of science fiction and fantasy fiction, as well as others, there are folks who have contributed to that field, or the broader community who have passed on and folks feel that the community should commemorate the achievements of those folks.

Meta sites are both about the *sites* they serve and the *community* they serve, and tend to have a little more flexibility of "is this a question?". Simply we have a tool that happens to work well for us (Q&A) and the meta sites use the platform to serve *their* needs—be it being used for announcements, or memorialising people of importance to us within or external to the site.

While not all sites would choose to do this, it’s more important the meta sites fit the *needs* of their community than a strict idea of what the site should be.

Answer (score 5):

> Should such types of questions be allowed on per-site metas, since they, well, aren't asking questions?

Depends on what the site wants. Just because it isn't asking a question doesn't mean it's unsuitable for a per site meta. For example, some sites have sandboxes and those don't ask a question either.

> More specifically, should questions like these posted on per-site metas be downvoted and/or closed?

Depends on what the site wants. If you were to post the same post as the one that sparked this on the meta of one of the sites I moderate, I would unilaterally close it, downvote it *and delete* it. If I'm feeling generous I might leave a comment too. Apparently other sites handle things differently.